# add KMS key to lambda environment using cdk

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cdk

Is it possible using the CDK to encrypt the environment variables for a lambda? I don't see the API supporting it - but you can from the AWS console

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found a soln:

```
const cfnFunction = func.node.findChild('Resource') as CfnFunction
cfnFunction.kmsKeyArn =
```